# rpmbuild error: command $`\r` not found

Tags: newline, fedora, rpmbuild, build-error

I'm running an rpm spec file, and encountering the following error:

```
$ rpmbuild -ba gregorio.spec 
Executing(%prep): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.dDWqRV
+ umask 022
+ cd /home/cantanima/rpmbuild/BUILD
+ cd /home/cantanima/rpmbuild/BUILD
+ rm -rf gregorio-2.4.1
+ /usr/bin/tar -xf -
+ /usr/bin/gzip -dc /home/cantanima/rpmbuild/SOURCES/gregorio-2.4.1.tar.gz
+ STATUS=0
+ '[' 0 -ne 0 ']'
+ cd gregorio-2.4.1
+ /usr/bin/chmod -Rf a+rX,u+w,g-w,o-w .
+ $'\r'
/var/tmp/rpm-tmp.dDWqRV: line 39: $'\r': command not found
error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.dDWqRV (%prep)
```

The script file `/var/tmp/rpm-tmp.dDWqRV` has the following lines in that area:

```
if [ $STATUS -ne 0 ]; then
  exit $STATUS
fi
cd 'gregorio-2.4.1'
/usr/bin/chmod -Rf a+rX,u+w,g-w,o-w .

autoreconf -f -i
```

Line 39 is the one immediately above `autoreconf -f -i`. It's a blank line, apparently marked by `\r` instead of a standard Linux carriage return. **If I change that one line in a text editor, the script runs fine.**

As far as I can tell, this script file is automatically generated by `rpmbuild`, not by the spec file, though I don't honestly know. What am I doing to cause this? I'm running Fedora 20, rpmbuild version 4.11.3.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A little more work did it. Apparently, when I downloaded the `.spec` file, either my email provider or my web browser gave it a DOS encoding ('\r\n'). I opened it up in a text editor, switched it to Unix encoding ('\n') and all is fine — now `rpmbuild` runs happily.